# How to block embed flash access to the internet?

Tags: html, flash

Is there any way to block an embed flash from accessing the internet? The idea is to block ads that appear "internally". I have it embed in the traditional way, as follows:

```
<object width="500" height="600">
    <param name="movie" value="file.swf"></param>
    <embed scr="file.swf" width="500" height="600" />
</object>
```

Comment: Is there a reason to have them output at all when the site is viewed internally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the IP address or the host name where Flash is connecting to, you could modify your web servers hosts file (in linux at /etc/hosts) so that requests to certain IP address are routed to the servers localhost (127.0.0.1).

Comment: Of course if those hosts ever change, you'll need to update the redirects.

Answer (score 0):

You mean from within the page that serves it, for all users that open the page? I don't think so, no.

You would have to have access to the Flash movie itself, and remove the external references - something that is probably forbidden by the Author's T&C if you're working with an external product.